# Какие форматы видео для iphone поддерживают альфа канал?

Tags: html, apple

Мне нужно вставить видео на сайт но iphone как оказалось не поддерживает кучу форматов с альфа каналом. Я использую webm. Есть ли формат для iphone который поддерживает альфа канал? Мне нужно выводить видео с прозрачностью.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [этому](https://pixelbakery.co/recipes/list-of-video-image-formats-in-2021-supporting-alpha-channels) и [этому](https://caniuse.com/?search=hevc) источнику единственным вариантом для старых версий iOS представляется HEVC, который однако поддерживается по сути только Safari на MacOS начиная с версии 13 и на iOS начиная с версии 11. WebM поддерживается [начиная с iOS 15](https://9to5mac.com/2021/08/10/apple-adding-webm-audio-codec-support-to-safari-with-ios-15/).